# Barcode reader calling submit function in my form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drupal-7, barcode

I have a simple form to recharge account. In this account i am reading the card number through bar code reader but this bar code reader calls the submit function immediately after putting the value in it. I want to stop bar code reader from calling the submit function because i have other fields to fill before submit.
I want to know how can i stop bar code reader calling submit function j query.

Comment: What barcode software are you using? What does *your* code look like?

Comment: it is honeywell barcode reader after connecting it its automatically install the driver cd. I have one simple drupal7 form element with two text box in which one accepts data through barcode reader.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(":input").keypress(function(event){
    if (event.which == '10' || event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

I used this jquery to solve my problem to prevent it calling submit function

Answer (score 2):

I believe most barcode scanners are programmed out of the box to add a carriage return /line feed character at the end of a scan. The effect is basically like a user hitting enter. I would see what you could do with the keydown event. First output to see which character codes it adds to the end of the input. Then write a small conditional to  preventDefault / stopPropagation when those codes are detected.

Depending on the scanner, it might be programmable as well.

Comment: I solved this issue by using j query script to prevent it from calling submit function